# Standard way to round integer down to nearest multiple of 4

Tags: c

I want to round an integer, `i`, down to the nearest multiple of 4.

For example:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 0
2 -> 0
3 -> 0
4 -> 4
5 -> 4
6 -> 4
7 -> 4
8 -> 8
9 -> 8
```

The obvious way for me to do this would be:

```
i = (i / 4) * 4;
```

But I have been criticised for using this because supposedly it is unclear, and looks like a mistake.

I am aware of the obvious alternative, bitwise shifting:

```
i = (i >> 2) << 2;
```

But I then realised that there is a different approach entirely:

```
(i | 3) - 3
```

Sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 4*4; i++) {
        printf("%d %d %d %d\n", i, (i / 4) * 4, (i >> 2) << 2, (i | 3) - 3);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to know the standard way to do this, and if a modern compiler with highest optimisation will be intelligent enough to convert my code to the fastest method.

Comment: The quickest is `i & ~3`.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I was about to suggest that, but pedantically speaking, I *think* it might be IB. That said, it will probably work fine on all sane environments.

Comment: What should `-1` round to? 0? or -4?

Comment: To me the clearest way is `i -= i % 4;`. "Subtract the remainder"

Comment: @Mystical that's a good question! In my specific instance it is not relevant since i is always positive, but I think -4 is more appropriate in that situation because it means there are always 4 numbers in a row with the same value after the operation.

Comment: Certainly not 0. `-1 & ~3` is `-4` on any twos-complement binary system.

Comment: With the (i / 4) * 4, when i is -1, the value goes to 0.

Comment: please remember: C does not enforce the twos complement to represent negative numbers

Comment: C doesn't, that's true. The marketplace seems to, though. Run across any BCD machines lately?

Comment: also be careful then using shifts, since they rely un a special representation of negative numbers and are even not defined (implementation defined behaviour) for negative ints.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker hasnt to do with bcd. negative values also may be represented by ones complement or signed magnitude format. even the position of the signbit may vary or numbers may contain padding bits.

Comment: Yeah, but still pretty rare.

Comment: btw, I just tried all 4 of these in GCC on O2. `(i >> 2) << 2` and `i & 3` compile to the same thing (`andl $3, %eax`). `(i | 3) - 3` compiles to 2 instructions. `(i / 4) * 4` is by far the worst as it has a compare and conditional move. (since it has different behavior for negative numbers)

Comment: what `(i >> 2) << 2` does is compiler dependent. that the last is the worst ist clear because it has to handle negative numbers separately.

Comment: is `int` really the correct datatype, or would `unsigned int` more appropriate?  Bit shift operations on (signed) integer are undefined so they should be avoided.

Answer (score 6):

This is a matter of opinion. My opinion is that:

```
i = (i / 4) * 4;
```

is the best way. It's simple, and it obviously gives the right answer.  Any other code you write, someone reading it will have to stop and think about what it's doing and whether it might have any corner cases that don't work.

One issue that may come up is what to do when `i` is negative. C uses "truncation towards zero", so if `i` is negative then this expression gives the negative of doing it on `abs(i)`.

An equivalent way is:

```
i -= (i % 4);
```

which is also simple and clear.

Comment: Is the multiplication/division way or the modulus way more expensive?

Comment: @AndyJ the compiler's job is to select the more efficient assembly for the requested behaviour

Comment: @AndyJ Yes, multiplication/division is an order of magnitude more expensive. It depends on the CPU, but multiplications with generally be about 15-25 CPU cycles, division and modulus are around 30-50 CPU cycles, and a bitwise operator like `|` or `>>` would be 1 CPU cycle. Compilers are often smart enough to optimize it, but there are a lot of edge cases a compiler can miss. If you are dealing with performance sensitive code, you should check the assembly output of your compiler to make sure the optimization took place. Better to just do the bitwise version in performance-sensitive code.

Answer (score 2):

create a function thats named in a way that it is clear that it should do and use this function:

```
static inline int roundToMultipleOf4(int v){
  return (v/4)*4;
}
```

So when using your function it is clear that the code is supposed to do and then looking at the functiondefinition it becomes also clear why the division straight is followed by the multiplication.

Comment: But that's still no excuse for using division at all.

Comment: He was not blamed for using the division. but for writing unclear code. Besides that the compiler will optimize out the division and use shifts or even some bit manipulation

Comment: @WeatherVane no! as a rule of thumb you can say: if you have to comment the code, you should rewrite (eg by extracting unclear parts and give them a meaningful name) it. Do not mix up comment (not in the meaning of the syntactical element) and documentation (thats that comments (the syntactical elements) are for).

Comment: For something this mundane, I'd recommend a macro instead of a function name, personally.  But also, for something this mundane, I'm not sure I see why (v/4)*4 is unclear.  Seems clear to me.

Comment: I still don't see why OP's `i = (i / 4) * 4;` looks like a mistake. Does `xor eax,eax` look like a mistake too?

Comment: no, but this is a good example where it leads to write something to do something other. This lead to quite few circumstances. because modern processors are deeply pipelined such expressions can cause trouble and a lot of stall cycle. So te get the code fast that nearly anybody think should be faster than a direct immediate load. extra logic has to be implemented in the CPU to detect such expressions and detect the nonexistent read dependency.